# Oclick with Seaborn stripplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have onlclick working fine with Seaborn scatterplot, but when I use stripplot and click on any point it returns incorrect data.  Is onlclick supported with stripplot?
Here is my code snippet:

```
def relation_graph(x_series, y_series, hue_series, sheetname):
    df =  open_file_read_to_df(filename, sheetname)
    def onpick(event):
        ind = event.ind
        print('7-digit DN:', df.iloc[ind].index.values)

    plots = sns.scatterplot(y= y_series, x = x_series, hue=hue_series, data=df, picker=4)
```

Simplified version:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

def relation_graph(df, x_series, y_series, hue_series):
    def onpick(event):
        ind = event.ind
        print('Found:', df.iloc[ind].index.values)
    plots = sns.stripplot(y= y_series, x = x_series, hue=hue_series, data=df, picker=4)
    plots.figure.canvas.mpl_connect("pick_event", onpick)
    plt.show()

data = [["test1", 1, 2, "red"], ["test2", 1, 2, "blue"], ["test3", 2, 5, "red"], ["test4", 3, 2, "blue"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['name', 'X', 'Y', "Color"])
df.set_index("name", inplace=True)
relation_graph(df, df['X'], df['Y'], df['Color'])
```

Comment: `scatterplot` keeps the original order of the data, but `stripplot` reorders them. So, you can't use `event.id`. You can still use `onclick`, but without the `event.id`. If the `x,y` values are all unique, you could look them up again. Or, if they're not unique, you could look up them all and display the desired extra info of the set.

Comment: I don't think it's right that stripplot reorders the data (that is true of swarmplot in <=0.11) but what it does do is plot separate artists for each categorical level, which you'd need to account for when mapping back from the click index to the original dataframe.

Comment: @mwaskom would you have an example of a way to do that?

Comment: @ChrisD it would be easier for someone to cook something up if you provided complete/runnable example code of what you're trying to accomplish (using one of the example seaborn datasets is best)